# Perl using Date::Parse module unable to print <STDIN> date in different format

Tags: perl

I want to accept a user date on the command line in format

dd/mm/yyyy

then print the date out to the user in

yyyy/mm/dd

I am trying to use the Date::Parse module to parse into a date to be reprinted.

The [Date:Parse docs](https://metacpan.org/pod/Date::Parse) show that I should be able to get $day, $month and $year from user input.

```
use Date::Parse;

$time = str2time($date);

($ss,$mm,$hh,$day,$month,$year,$zone) = strptime($date);
```

This is my current code:

```
use strict;
use Date::Parse;

print "Enter a date in dd/mm/yyy format: ";
my $user_date = <STDIN>;
my @date      = strptime($user_date);

# ( $day, $month, $year ) = strptime($user_date);
# my $user_day = ( ($day) = strptime($user_date) );
print "%Y/%m/%d", @date;
```

However the print fails and it appears from output that entered 10 of 10 is 9 in output.

Output

```
Enter a date in dd/mm/yyy format: 16/10/1952
%Y/%m/%d1952916s
```

What should I do?

Comment: `print "%Y/%m/%d", @date;` - [print](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/print.html) does not interpolate [sprintf](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sprintf.html)-style replacements. You want `print sprintf ...`, or just [printf](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/printf.html)

Comment: @Corion: And those aren't `sprintf`-style placeholders anyway :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The documentation for Date::Parse isn't clear, but it looks like you get the values back in the format that `localtime()` would expect. The year, for example, seems to be the year minus 1900. This means that the month number will be 0 to 11 rather than 1 to 12.

Date::Parse hasn't been updated for over five years. I'd suggest that it should best be avoided these days. There are much better options to choose from. These include [Time::Piece](https://metacpan.org/pod/Time::Piece) that has been included as a standard part of the Perl distribution since version 5.10.0. You can use its `strptime()` (string parse time) method to parse your string and its `strftime()` (string format time) method to format the date object as you like.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

use Time::Piece;

print "Enter a date in dd/mm/yyy format: ";
chomp(my $user_date = <STDIN>);

my $tp = Time::Piece->strptime($user_date, '%d/%m/%Y');

say $tp->strftime('%Y/%m/%d');
```

**Update:**

Also, it's really not clear what this line is supposed to do:

```
print "%Y/%m/%d", @date;
```

I think you were thinking of using the `strftime()` method from POSIX.pm.

```
print strftime "%Y/%m/%d", @date;
```

But with `use warnings` this generates warnings because of all the undefined values in `@data` (that's a rather bizarre design decision in that module and, in my opinion, another reason to avoid it). You can fix that by replacing:

```
my @date      = strptime($user_date);
```

With:

```
my @date      = map { $_ // 0 } strptime($user_date);
```